# Calculate javascript date

Tags: javascript, date

i have the date `2013-12-28` and i want add one or more more day to it. so if i add one more day it will be `2013-12-29`. 
i try to add it by adding the value of it's date (date 28+1), it works, but what if i add 7 more day to it? the date will be 35, and of course it is not a valid date format.
can someone help me?
here's the example of my script:

```
var d = new Date();
var Y = d.getFullYear();
var M = d.getMonth()+1;
var D = d.getDate();
var DT = d.getDate()+1;// what if i + 20 days from today? the format would be invalid

var today = Y+"-"+M+"-"+D;
var tomorrow = Y+"-"+M+"-"+DT;
alert(today+" <> "+tomorrow);
// "<>" means nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a date object as in the code you show:

```
 var d = new Date();
```

...then you can add 7 days to it like this:

```
d.setDate( d.getDate() + 7 );
```

...and it will automatically increment the month if needed.

Further reading:

- [The `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [`.getDate()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)
- [`.setDate()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

If you need to extract the year, month and day in order to format the result a particular way do so *after* adding days.

Comment: +1, never knew setDate will do auto increment

Comment: aha, setDate(). it helps :D

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this using [getdate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), [setdate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [getdate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 7);
```

Comment: yes,, setDate(). it helps

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi:- Yes it does the trick for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert your date string into unix timestamp, and them add 3600 * 24 * *<number of days>* to the timestamp and them convert it back to date string.

The code can be as follows:

```
function addDaysToDate(date, days) {
    var time = Date.parse(date) + days * 24 * 3600;
    date = new Date(time);
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();
}
var date = '2013-12-28';
console.log(addDaysToDate(date, 7));
```